# Way to divide up Earth for post-apo story purposes

Tags: science-fiction, geography, post-apocalypse

So, I'm basicly creating world in which most of terrain which isn't shoreline, mountain or plateu is shrouded in "Mist" (with capital "m") which renders this terrain inaccesable for people, they are traversed with appropriate equipment on in airships (this is solved) but i do not now exactly know which terrains to leave habitable and which to put under Mist. I'd like to have Carpats, Alps and the big part of Russia uncovered. Asian, European, African, Australian, North American, South American regions can have differently working Mist, it can decay by humidity, height and other factors. If someone can, please say where to put mist and where to leave space for people I would be very thankful.

Comment: What are your criteria for where to place Mist?

Comment: If this is only an issue of elevation, try using [FloodMap.net](http://www.floodmap.net/) to see what happens when you think of Mist as a rising sea level (how much unaffected land is left behind).  But, if you're trying to achieve specific goals with the Mist, then @Raditz_35 is correct, we need a list of goals, limits, criteria, etc.

Comment: It decays with humidity and height, yet the Mist is specifically located where humidity and altitude are the highest?

Comment: Rather than being forced to answer your own question about Mist, perhaps you should just tell us how many isolated groups you want and about how many survivors you want left in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fog generators.**

[image: shimmer from annihilation]
http://lightgungalaxy.com/2018/03/03/the-ending-of-annihilation-explained/

The image is from the recent horror movie Annihilation: there is a discrete, visible zone inside of which there is badness going down.  This zone of badness concept has been done many times.  HP Lovecraft's story ["The Color Out of Space"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Colour_Out_of_Space) has such a zone.

> In the tale, an unnamed narrator pieces together the story of an area
>   known by the locals as the "blasted heath" in the wild hills west of
>   Arkham, Massachusetts. The narrator discovers that many years ago a
>   meteorite crashed there, poisoning every living being nearby;
>   vegetation grows large but foul tasting, animals are driven mad and
>   deformed into grotesque shapes, and the people go insane or die one by
>   one.

So too your fog.  It is produced by sources centered in the fog belts.  There can be as many of these as you need, of greater or lesser fog generating potency.  Fog drifts away from these sources becoming weaker with distance.  If it helps your story you can state outright what is generating the fog, or have your protagonists figure it out (which would give narrative energy!), or leave it unexplained.  The fog might be from alien meteorites as in the Lovecraft story, or some military experiment gone awry, or something purely supernatural according to the type of story you have.